# Checking details of levels adjustment after adjusting

Tags: gimp

I adjusted levels manually on a picture and would like to know the values to apply the same adjustment on other similar images. Does GIMP let me view those settings after the fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are automatically saved as a preset when you apply them. You can retrieve the settings by clicking on the drop-down selector at the top of any adjustment dialog next to the label "Presets". The text boxes will then be populated by the settings of your previous adjustment.

In this screenshot, the levels adjustment on 2019-12-02 is the only one I applied:

[image: Retrieve settings with the adjustment dialog]

You can also save it explicitly with a more descriptive name by clicking the `+` icon to the right of the drop-down selector.

Comment: How can such a positive icon become depressed? 